# jQuery Color Cycling Animation On Multiple Elements

Tags: jquery

I've worked out the colour cycling with the below snipppet and I've got it working on both my h1 titles and my buttons.

However, there is a slight delay between the two elements and I'd like the colour cycling to occur at the same time.

I'm not super familiar with JS/JQuery, but is it possible to combine the 2 into 1 so that the colour cycling syncs up between the elements, as well as remove some of the repetitive code?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

// Text Colour Cycling 
$('.colours h1').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        colors = ['#ec008c', '#00bcc3', '#5fb26a', '#fc7331'];

    setInterval(function(){
        var color = colors.shift();
        colors.push(color);
        $this.animate({color: color}, 1500);
    },4000);
});

// Button BG Colour Cycling 
$('.colours a.button').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        colors = ['#ec008c', '#00bcc3', '#5fb26a', '#fc7331'];

    setInterval(function(){
        var color = colors.shift();
        colors.push(color);
        $this.animate({backgroundColor: color}, 1500);
    },4000);
});

});
```

Comment: I will go better with [CSS3 transition property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this code to do what You need in a more synchronized and concise way. I tested this with .css() instead of .animate() as the latter did not work for me, but the question and answer are valid.

```
var colors = ['#ec008c', '#00bcc3', '#5fb26a', '#fc7331'];

$(document).ready(function( $ ){

setInterval(function(){
   var color = colors.shift();
   colors.push(color);
   $('.colours a.button').each(function() {$(this).animate({backgroundColor: color}, 1500)});
     $('.colours h1').each(function() {$(this).animate({color: color}, 1500)});
},4000);
// Text Colour Cycling 

});
```

Comment: Tested and that simplified code does indeed work (thanks!), however the timing for the button and text colour cycle are still off by about a second. Should I just try to play with the timings or is there a better way to sync them up? 
  
Also, if I wanted to have multiple instances of the colour change (using different colours and different classes) would I need to wrap your modified snippet is some sort of function?

Comment: What browser are You using? How does your HTML look like? Being out of sync by second sounds like there is a different issue at hand.

Comment: I'm using Chrome but I tested it in Edge and Firefox with the same result.  If it helps for a visual, I'm testing it [on this page](https://www.creativecollab.co/colour-cycle-test).

Comment: Hi, I just went to that page using chrome and I can't see any issue there. The colors go at the same time. I also recorded a movie using my mobile to have different view. F1nally I used F12 tools in Browser and used `margin-top:-70px` on the background animated element to make them overlap, to see color gaps if any, and I still can't see issue there. It might be You fixed it and did not tell us :) Or, which makes more sense for me, You have the code in one of the multiple linked JS files and for some reason Your browser still loads the cached version of the script, so You still see the issue.